# Can't zoom Google map iOS using elm

Tags: ios, google-maps, elm

I would like to use pinch to zoom in/out with iOS. My code for map is following:

```
continentalUsMapOptions : GoogleMaps.CreateMapOptions    
continentalUsMapOptions =    
  { center = Just usaCenterLatLng    
  , disableDefaultUI = Just True    
  , mapTypeControlPosition = Nothing    
  , mapTypeId = Nothing      
  , maxZoom = Just 6    
  , minZoom = Just 2    
  , rotateControlPosition = Nothing    
  , scrollWheel = Just False    
  , signInControl = Just False    
  , streetViewControlPosition = Nothing    
  , styles = List.map Style.toJson mapStyles    
  , zoomGestures = Just True    
  , zoomControlPosition = Nothing    
  }
```

Unfortunately, zoomGestures is not working at all.  Link to page is: https://sre.com

Comment: On iOS, I can pinch to zoom but as soon as I release it, the map snaps back to its original zoom level. On desktop, I can't zoom at all, although obviously that's because you've disabled `scrollWheel`.

Comment: Are you using this library?
https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-google-maps

Comment: I made enable 'scrollWheel', still not working.